# Is it possible to have 2 materials reference same shader in Blender

Tags: materials, shaders

I'd like to be able to have same material in Blender with 2 different names. It should work in a way that if I edit the shader in Blender in one of the materials, it will update in both materials. Is this possible?

Comment: Using a node group?

Comment: wrapping the whole shader in node group? that might work

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3g4LSx6MSBA for instance